# Pass On Get Results from one class to another - Flutter

Tags: flutter

The data `unLockCard`  is properly created in the main class where the button is placed.

When I moved the button to a dialog in a different class - the `unLockCard`  is lost. I receive the error message [image: mentionning that]

What is the best way to pass on `unLockCard[number] = tarots[0];` into a different widget or class.

Homepage

```
  List<bool> flips = [false, false, false, false];
  List tarots = [];
  List unLockCard = [];
Widget _buildTarotCard(key, number, title) {
    return  Column(
      children: [
        FlipCard(
          key: key,
          flipOnTouch: true,
          front: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              tarots.shuffle();
              key.currentState.toggleCard();
              setState(() {
                flips[number] = true;
              });
              unLockCard[number] = tarots[0];
              tarots.removeAt(0);
            },
```

Dialog

```
  Widget _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
     Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showAlert(context));
     return       Container(
       color: Color(0xFF2C3D50),
       );
   }
     void showAlert(BuildContext context) {
       List unLockCard = [];
 Dialogs.materialDialog(
       color: colorTitle,
       msg: 'Congratulations, you won 500 points',
       msgStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
       title: 'Congratulations',
       titleStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
       lottieBuilder: Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/spirituality.json',
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
       ),
       dialogWidth: kIsWeb ? 0.3 : null,
       context: context,
       actions: [

                 NeumorphicButton(
                         onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.DETAILS,
                             arguments: unLockCard.sublist(0, 4)),
                         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit cluttered. You are building a new `List unLockCard = [];` in the showAlert() method even though you have one already in the HomePage. I suggest you create a `CardController` class that deals with everything card related and use it in all the views you need. One very elegant way I found is by using the GetX library (https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx). You can declutter your code using a GetView and a GetController (https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#getview). However, if you don't want to add a new library to your project, you can achieve the same results by having a single point that deals with card actions (i.e. holds a single instance of the `unlockCard` list and updates it accordingly).